# What's the natural metric/topology on infinite derivations?

Tags: proof-theory

In the appendix to the SEP Proof Theory [article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/appendix-f.html), Michael Rathjen makes reference to a topology on infinite derivations for which a variant of cut-elimination is a continuous function. The referenced paper by Mints is not very explicit. Another common referenced paper is by Kreisel, Mints, and Simpson ([paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0064871)) where the following description is given.

> The most obvious additional requirement on $\rho$, suggested by this step is continuity of $\rho$, where a neighborhood of a derivation is determined (as is usual for trees) by a finite number of finite initial paths in the given derivation tree.

**Is this just the topology on Baire space where basic open sets are infinite paths extending a finite path?** It appears so, but I would like some verification that I'm understanding this description correctly. Pointers to introductory material that discusses this in more detail would also be very appreciated.